# Xpath: not supported by FireFox, but Chrome OK

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver, xpath

WebDriver Xpath: not supported by FireFox:

```
//div[@class='foo']//*[name()='div' or name()='span' or name()='input' and @type='text']
```

But this is working for Chrome. Is this Xpath 1.0?

how to fix it for firefox? Is there a way to verify xpath in firefox browser?

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML ?

Comment: You say it's "not supported" and/or "not working", but you haven't told us the symptoms. How does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options.

```html
<html><head></head><body>
        <div class="foo">
   <div><input type="text"></div>
   <span type="text"></span>
   <label> ... </label>
   <div type="text"></div>
   <input type="text">
  </div>
</body></html>
```

**Option 1:**

```
//div[@class='foo']//*[@type='text'][local-name()='div' or local-name()='span' or local-name()='input']
```

[image]

**Option 2:**
    //div[@class='foo']//div[@type='text']|//div[@class='foo']//span[@type='text']|//div[@class='foo']//input[@type='text']

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's legal XPath 1.0. You might like to add parentheses in the condition to make quite sure that you, the reader, and the XPath processor all share the same understanding of the operator precedence of "or" and "and".

Can't help you diagnose a problem if you don't tell us the symptoms.